# How can I access a specific folder inside firebase storage from a cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am using firebase cloud function storage for the first time.
 I succeeded to
perform changes on the default folder by using :

```
exports.onFileUpload = functions.storage.bucket().object().onFinalize(data => {
const bucket = data.bucket;
const filePath = data.name;
const destBucket = admin.storage().bucket(bucket);
const file = destBucket.file(filePath);
```

but now I want  the function to be triggered from a folder inside the storage 
folder like this
[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to configure trigger conditions for certain file paths, similar to what you can do with database triggers.

i.e. you **can not** set a cloud storage trigger for `'User_Pictures/{path}'`

What you have to do is to inspect [the object attributes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events#access_storage_object_attributes) once the function is triggered and handle it accordingly there.

Either you create a trigger function for each case you want to handle and stop the function if it's not the path you're looking for.

```
functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {
  if (!object.name.startsWith('User_Pictures/')) {
    console.log(`File ${object.name} is not a user picture. Ignoring it.`);
    return null;
  }

  // ...
})
```

Or you do a master handling function that dispatches the processing to different functions

```
functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {
  if (object.name.startsWith('User_Pictures/')) {    
    return handleUserPictures(object);
  } else if (object.name.startsWith('MainCategoryPics/')) {
    return handleMainCategoryPictures(object);
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly . I will mark it as the right answer. but i want to enter a folder inside User_Pictures folder like User_Pictures/{id}/profilePics can you specify how to do that?

Comment: Google cloud storage actually [doesn't have any concept of hierarchical folder structure](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork). So you need to use regex or string splitting the `/` character to complete your task.