# Firebase cloud functions master handling function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53977904/1792528) a master handling function that dispatches the processing to different functions was suggested.

```js
    functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {
      if (object.name.startsWith('User_Pictures/')) {    
        return handleUserPictures(object);
      } else if (object.name.startsWith('MainCategoryPics/')) {
        return handleMainCategoryPictures(object);
      }
    })
```

I have tried implementing this by having `index.js` as follows:

```js
const handler = require('./handler');
exports.handler = handler.handler;

exports.userpictures = require('./userpictures');
exports.mainpictures = require('./mainpictures');
```

And in `mainpictures.js` having the following:

```
exports.handleMainCategoryPictures= async (object) => { ... code here ... }
```

When I ran `firebase deploy` no functions were detected. I was expecting 3. Is this type of structure possible, am I making some obvious mistake in terms of exporting correctly? When I tried exporting directly without the handler the functions were detected.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to define your exported functions with the functions builder API.  That's thing that goes like this in your first code bit:

```
export fun = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(...)
```

If you aren't using this API to build and export functions from index.js, then the Firebase CLI will find no function, and nothing will be deployed.  You can use this API from a required file, if you want, but index.js must still ultimately export a function built like this.

If you are, in fact, using this and not showing it here, then I suggest you edit the question to show the [complete, minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of all the files in play.

Comment: right, I was trying to factor out the `onFinalize()` out into a handler function to reduce the amount of duplication in each exported function of checking the mimetype, path, etc. From your answer I could have the first code bit, as `export finalizeHandler = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(...)`. My goal is to have multiple functions in firebase that get called when necessary and reduce the overhead of all being triggered on any write to storage.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do.  So what's the specific problem?  You can't avoid using the function builder, as I said.  You can still delegate to other functions exported from other files on a case-by-case basis.  Just require and call them as needed from your main onFinalize callback.